# Merge CSV files on GCS using PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client, gsutil

I have multiple small CSV files in a GCS bucket. I'm trying to merge those into a single large CSV file.
I've seen it can be done using "gsutil compose" command, but I was wondering if that can be done using the PHP Google Cloud Storage API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the [Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects#storage_compose_object-php) that references this other [link](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.138.0/storage/bucket?method=compose). And the code should be something like this

```
  $sourceObjects = ['log1.txt', 'log2.txt']; 
  $singleObject = $bucket->compose($sourceObjects, 'combined-logs.txt');
```